# Dynamic array without new (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and this is a very basic question.

In C++ there are only two ways to create dynamic arrays *(read in a book, correct me if I'm wrong)* using memory allocation either by `new` operator or `malloc()` function which is taken from C.

When declaring an array `int array[size]`, the square brackets `[]` *must* have a `const`.

However in the following code `size` is an `unsigned int` variable.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    unsigned int size;
    cout<<"Enter size of the array : ";
    cin>>size;
    int array[size]; // Dynamically Allocating Memory
    cout<<"\nEnter the elements of the array\n";
    // Reading Elements
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout<<" :";
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    // Displaying Elements
    cout<<"\nThere are total "<<size<<" elements, as listed below.";
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        cout<<endl<<array[j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling g++ throws no error and moreover the program runs perfectly.

**Question 1 :** Could this be another way to create dynamic array?

**Question 2 :** Is the code correct?

**Question 3 :** If `[]` can only contain `const`, why does the code work?

Comment: g++ extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length

Comment: It is not standards compliant C++. It is a compiler extension. You can set the compiler flags to be more strict about compliance (`-std=c++11` or `-std=c++98`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Correct, you have discovered [a `gcc` extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length). This has been allowed in C for a long time, but it has not made it into C++ standard until the C++14.
2. Yes, the code is correct, assuming that you are fine with using non-portable extensions to the language.
3. This is true about standard-compliant compilers. You can tell `gcc` that you do not want to use extensions by supplying a `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++11` compiler flag.

If you need a dynamically-sized array in C++, a better approach would be to use `std::vector<T>`. It gives you the flexibility of dynamically allocated array, and takes care of managing the allocated memory for you.

Comment: It's not in C++14, either. I believe they're waiting on an acceptable library wrapper now because `std::dynarray` failed.

Comment: Not in C++17 or 20, either. About 3: gcc will still happily compile variable length arrays, even when specifying `-std=c++11` or any other version. If you add `-pedantic`, it will issue a warning, and with `-pedantic-errors` it will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

> In C++ there are only two ways to create dynamic arrays (read in a
>   book, correct me if I'm wrong) using memory allocation either by new
>   operator or malloc() function which is taken from C.

This depends on what you mean by **dynamic**.

From a strictly technical perspective, in the context of the lifetime of an object, **dynamic** means something with *dynamic storage duration*.  A storage duration is how long an object will live after it has been created.  An object that has *dynamic storage duration* will continue to live on until it is explicitly destroyed.  (Note that this explicit destruction may be obfuscated through the use of smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`)

However this does not seem to be what you're really asking about in this question.  You seem to be asking:

> If I want to create a container for objects, but I don't know how big
>   that container needs to be until runtime, is `new` and `malloc` my
>   only choice?

The answer to *that* question is **no**.  And in fact, in modern C++ using `new` should be a choice of last resort, and using `malloc` should be even more last-resort than that.

Instead of trying to create a C-style array of `N` elements, use a `vector` instead:

```
std::vector <int> myInts;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  myInts.push_back (i);
```

This has several advantages:

1. You don't have to `delete` anything
2. You don't have to know how many elements will be put in to the `vector` before you create the `vector` -- just keep adding elements until you're done
3. `vector` is *guaranteed* to have contigious storage, meaning the elements can be accessed using `operator[]` just like a C-style array

Comment: What do you mean by contiguous? As in, the elements of `vector` are always in series in the memory? Or by that you mean a `vector` element points to the next `vector` element and `[]` notation is used to access its elements. In latter, the elements might not be contiguous in the memory.

Comment: @SurajThapar: Contigious as in in series in memory.

Comment: Well that sounds wrong. Memory Chunks/Memory = [░░▓▓░▓▓░░░▓░░▓░▓▓] , ▓ = Unavailable space, ░ = Free memory. Where each chunk represents `<int>`'s size. Suppose if `vector` decides to keep the first element in the left most free memory, it will only be able to store 2 elements. As you said that one *doesn't have to know how many elements will be put into the `vector` before you create it*. So it will have to break the statement [3] i.e, contiguous storage (as in in series in memory) for it to avoid overflow.

Comment: @SurajThapar:  Right, `vector` manages the memory for you.  If you `push_back` something and there isn't enough `capacity`, `vector` will reallocate and move your elements to new space.  I promise -- the Standard **guarantees** that `vector` sores it's elements in contigious memory.